# Transparent SVG with Illustrator

Tags: svg, adobe-illustrator

How to create an SVG file with Transparent background using Adobe Illustrator?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A SVG always have a transparent background as long as you do not insert a rect or something that is filling the whole graphic or using CSS to set a background color for the root element.

If you have another issue, please come up with a basic example SVG to show your problem.

Answer (score 1):

A .svg is just like .png (in terms of a transparent background) except for the fact that it is a vector format as compared to .png which is a raster format (ie. it pixelates on zomming in)